# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 update/delete

Tags: mysql, laravel, debian

I ran into a very strange error: I am using laravel 4 and locally everything works fine. On my remote Server things are different though. I get a

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053
```

error on UPDATE and DELETE queries. The strange thing is, that even though the error screen prints out the query, it has still run and for example updated the values.

Can anybody give me a hint on why this error might occur? I'm stuck!

Here's my query:

```
$insert = DB::connection('mysql')->select("UPDATE shops set sector_id = '".$input['sector']."', category_id = '".$input['category']."', date_online = '".$input['date_online']."', date_signed = '".$input['date_signed']."', potential_sales = '".$potentialsales."', shop_system = '".$input['shopsytem']."' WHERE id = '".$input['id']."'");
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_no_result_set

Comment: I think we need some more information, can you add the code you are using?

Comment: @aconrad I checked that out already. Doesn't make sense, because the exact same code works locally. Thats the strange thing.

Comment: why ->select(  ?  is there ->update  ?

Comment: updated the methods and now it works - must be a higher security setting I guess. Locally on apache it works with select. thx!

Answer (score 2):

Update all methods to the proper methods (select,udpate,delete). Fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

reffer this link it may help you
http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=596

try DB::statement